# Pandas Groupby pct_change no pad

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Doing a percentage change and all works well except for the padding i have tried to set pct_change(fill_method=None) but i get the error:

filled = getattr(self, fill_method)(limit=limit)

TypeError: getattr(): attribute name must be string

i group by names and expect the first 3 values of each name to be nan.  But what it does it treats all values as part of a list and computes pct_change to all.  In the example this works for foo but no other names.  please see code below.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


np.random.seed(7) 
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(40, 1))

a=10*('foo',)
b=10*('bar',)
c=10*('laa',)
d=10*('loo',)
df['names']=a+b+c+d

df['percentage_change']=df.groupby('names')[0].pct_change(periods=3)
```

what i get:

```
names      pct change
foo        nan
foo        nan
foo        nan
foo        -.7589
foo       .693195
...       ....
bar       -.6435
bar       -1.16857
bar       -.158
bar       -.582117
```

what i expect is

```
names      pct change
foo        nan
foo        nan
foo        nan
foo        -.7589
foo       .693195
...       ....
bar       nan
bar       nan
bar       nan
bar       -.582117
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a [known issue in `pandas 0.23`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/21200).

One workaround is to use an `apply`:

```
df['percentage_change'] = df.groupby('names')[0].apply(lambda x: x.pct_change(periods=3))

           0 names  percentage_change
0   1.690526   foo                NaN
1  -0.465937   foo                NaN
2   0.032820   foo                NaN
3   0.407516   foo          -0.758941
4  -0.788923   foo           0.693195
5   0.002066   foo          -0.937064
6  -0.000890   foo          -1.002185
7  -1.754724   foo           1.224202
8   1.017658   foo         491.675907
9   0.600499   foo        -675.425038
10 -0.625429   bar                NaN
11 -0.171548   bar                NaN
12  0.505299   bar                NaN
13 -0.261356   bar          -0.582117
14 -0.242749   bar           0.415048
15 -1.453241   bar          -3.876001
16  0.554580   bar          -3.121931
...
```

Comment: I have just checked: upgrading from pandas-0.23.4 to pandas-0.24.1 fixes the bug. From the github issue link, it seems it was fixed in pandas-0.24.0.